# Typescript: tsconfig outFile not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, atom-editor, tsconfig

I am using an Atom as development environment for AngularJs 2 project with typescript. I have added atom-typescript plugin in atom to support typescript. Atom is generating separate .js file for every .ts file. I wanted to generate single .js file for all .ts file. Therefore I added outFile setting under comilerOptions inside tsconfig.json. My tsconfig.json is as below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outFile": "./js/Deployment/single.js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

It looks fine but still when I compile project it generates empty single.js file at specified location. I am not understanding what I am missing here. I have installed atom-typescript version 8.2.0.

My package.json is as below.

```
{
  "name": "Pro1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's not an error preventing it from compiling?

Comment: what version of tsc are you using?

Comment: I was using 1.7.3. After upgrade to version 1.8, issue got resolved. Thanks    guys for prompt reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks fine but still when I compile project it generates empty single.js file at specified location

Check your `typescript` version. Update to 1.8

```
`"typescript": "^1.7.3"`
```

More : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#concatenate-amd-and-system-modules-with---outfile

Comment: You are right Basarat. That resolve my issue. I updated typescript to 1.8 and it works. Thanks alot.